# How is the philosophy conclusion symbol drawn?

Tags: symbols

Looks like this:
[image: Conclusion]

(Maybe called "therefore"?)

---

Also, what's a good guide for philosophy symbols in LaTeX?

Edit: Looked up http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf for "conclusion", "therefore" and "philosophy", and it's not what I'm looking for.

Edit 2: No, in page 35 what appears is not what I'm looking for. This symbol is drawn before the "conclusion" sentence in Philosophy, so it would be:

```
premise1
premise2
\conclusion conclusion
```

Edit 3: According to http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Symbols , `\vdash` is the symbol I need, But I'm not able to insert it into a sentence like this:

```
\vdash conclusion
```

It tells me:

```
Missing $ inserted.
Missing \endgroup inserted.
Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list enviroment.
\begin{document} ended by \end{enumerate}
Extra \endgroup
```

If I remove `\vdash` from the line it's inserted to, all these errors disappear and the document compiles correctly. Maybe I'm missing a package?

Comment: Did »[How to look up a symbol?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol)« reveal something?

Comment: See p35 of [this](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Comment: I'd say that `\vdash` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Pyrobisqit `\vdash` can only be used in math mode, like so, for instance: `$\vdash$`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is good practice to wrap your wrap the `\vdash` into a command.  That way you can change the command once in the preamble (say you suddenly need it bold, or larger, or whatever) and it will be changed everywhere in the document.  E.g.,

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\concl}{\ensuremath{\vdash}}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item [P1] first premise
\item [P2] second premise
\item [\concl] conclusion 
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sounds much cleaner indeed, applied to my LaTeX master template!

Answer (score 3):

Solved! What I did is this:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item [P1] Premise1
    \item [P2] Premise2
    \item [P3] Premise3
    \item [$\vdash$] Conclusion
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 2):

For what it is worth, http://gregorywheeler.org/latex/phil-style2.html provides a few esoteric philosophy symbols, plus links to sites for logicians.
There is also a now-defunct tex-blog (http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/) and Charles Tankley's guide to LaTeX for philosophers: http://www.charlietanksley.net/latex-guide.html

Comment: Hey! Those links are nothing short of awesome! I'm absolutely bookmarking this for future reference! Thanks a lot :)